# How to handle identifiers with a dot in angularjs or node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, solr

I am using SOLR, node.js and angularjs for my project.

I am fetching a SOLR document that has certain fields with a dot in them. For example `img.front:'milk.jpg'`.

I want to use this attribute to display image.

```
<img ng-src="img/{{product.img.front}}" alt="image caption" err-src="img/default-placeholder.jpg"  id="product-image">
```

This is giving me errors because `img.front` is not a valid identifier in angularjs.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  If you look at the value returned in a debugger; such as Chrome what do you see?  Usually, I would expect the dot notation to reference an object's property.  Have you tried to use associative array notation to access the value; like this: `product["img.front"]`

Comment: I am not getting an error as such. The issue is that when I say `product.img.front`, it looks for an object `img` with a property `front`. Since there is no such data it displays the default image.

Comment: Based on my understanding; a dot is not a valid character in a JavaScript variable.  Can you provide a plnkr or similar to demonstrate the problem you're having.  I'm not sure how to guide you.

Answer (score -1):

try using `product.img['front']` instead of `product.img.front`

Comment: No that doesn't work. Anyways, `img` is not an associative array